# Using a web api controller as dispatcher which redirects to other appropricate web api controller based on a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

.NET 4.5
Web Api

Is there any way where I could create a single web api for external callers (e.g. browser, biztalk etc.) to call with a parameter which then be used by  this dispatcher to call appropriate web api controller to build and send response back.

Comment: I don't want to use HttpClient. Is it possible through the use of Routing attributes? E.G, based on the property of incoming request (viewmodel) router calls specific method on web api controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
private string apiUrl = "http://www.example.com/api/Users/";

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id) {
      using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
           var getRequest = client.GetAsync(apiUrl + id);
           // Do stuff while you wait for response (Or you can do nothing)
           HttpResponseMessage response = await getRequest;
           return ResponseMessage(response);
      }
}
```

Some things to note here:

- `HttpClient` is used for sending out requests. It should be disposed after we finish using it. Therefore, we must enclose it inside an `using` statement.
- `apiUrl` should contain your target endpoint
- `HttpClient` only supports asynchronous operations, so your Web API action should also be asynchronous
- `ResponseMessage(response)` is a method inherited from base class `ApiController`, that converts a given `HttpResponseMessage` into a `ResponseMessageResult`

Answer (score 0):

Why not? You can use HttpClient class in a ASP.NET Web API method/resource and chain a request to other controller or completely different ASP.NET Web API host, and get the third-party API response and return it to the caller of the first one.

Actually you're looking for creating an API proxy.

For example, let's say you've a method in some `ApiController`:

```
private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
     // You can use the same request object of incoming proxy request
     // to make the actual API request.
     HttpRequestMessage request = ControllerContext.Request;

     // Manipulate the source request and add 
     // whatever content or params you want.
     // request.RequestUri should be set with the 
     // target API host in order to avoid an infinite loop ;)

     // HttpClient should be used as singleton 
     // instead of creating an instance for each request
     _client = new HttpClient();

     // You can send the exact request to the target API this way.
     return client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

At the end of the day, you might be sending requests to `http://myweb.com/proxy/api/users` which will actually be handled by sending a request to `http://myotherweb.com/api/users`.

It's all about turning the proxy request URI to the actual target API removing the `proxy` resource from the API path and setting the resulting URI to the `HttpRequestMessage.RequestUri` property:

```
// I'm hardcoding the target URI, but you would do it by replacing 
// "/proxy" with an empty string in the source URI
request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://myotherweb.com/api/users");
```

Comment: The `HttpClient` instance should be disposed. Also, please take into account that Web API 2 recommends the use of `IHttpActionResult` instead of `HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: `SendAsync(request)` would send a GET request to the same Web API that is sending the request, therefore creating an infinite loop

Comment: @MatiCicero About IHttpActionResult, It will depend on what you want to do. If you need lower level details... you still need HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: @MatiCicero About the second comment, since I've published the answer, check the comment where I put a warning about modifying the host in HttpResponseMessage.RequestUri to avoid the infinite loop.......................

Comment: @MatiCicero Finally, I've edited the answer to use a static HttpClient to show the right way of using it